# Getting child view from a fragment defined by a frame layout in XML

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an EditText 'names'.
It's defined within a nested fragment.
So the view hierarchy is Activity A -> Fragment intFrag-> ChildFragment -> EditText

I need the ID of the edittext from Fragment Fragment F.

```
My layout for intFrag.xml has:
       <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

which was replaced by the Fragment Manager
```

This code seems to give me a id for the frame in 'v', but I can't get the child edittext still? Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong? Note: I'm getting a null value in the  onActivityCreated() method of Fragment F

```
View v = getView().findViewById(R.id.intFrag);
e= (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

******Okay I figured something:(I'm still not sure on an explanation, so it would be helpful if someone can explain):

If I use the same code in OnStart(), the ID for the edittext gets a value. My FragmentTransaction was done in OnCreateView. I'd have thought I would be able to get references to the views in onActivityCreated. Or is that wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to access child views from a nested fragment, I would advise against it. I think in this case onActivityCreated is being called for the intFrag fragment before the child fragment is done creating it's view. onActivityCreated() is called after onCreateView(), but only for the current fragment, not for child fragments.

Ideally your child fragment would have methods to set or get whatever info you need from the EditText, and you would use them as needed, rather than trying to access and store the view directly.

Comment: You're right. I'll add on to that answer... I have access to the child views in onActivityCreated() for the child fragments, which is where the code would go.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    e= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.edittext);
```

Comment: No that doesn't work, I already did try that. 
I'm wondering if I'm accessing the fragment in a wrong way, as it's a frame in the layout file of the activity.

Comment: ooh, in that case you will have to make a new layout file and set the fragment's layout to that layout file. You cannot replace mainactivity with something that is a child of it's own layout.